# How can I remove chars from index 0 to index of charAt

Tags: java, string, substring

I have this basic java question that I would like to get an answer: I need to remove all characters in a String from the beginning to an index determined by a char.

`String str = "And the priest said: Come to me, you sinners"`. I want to remove the char from the **"A"** to **":"** so the result would be `"Come to me, you sinners"`.

I tried with `str.substring(0, str.charAt(str.indexOf(":"))` `str2 = str.replace(str, "")`... and some other variations without success. The whole str content get removed, or doesn't work etc..

Please help, I know this is such a basic question but I got confused and failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drop the `str.charAt`; and to select after the `:`, just add 1 to the `indexOf`:

```
str.substring(str.indexOf(":") + 1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I finally figured out how to use the remaining chars